# Why is my header double the height in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, header, height, double

Hi guys I'm very new to webdesign and the more I learn the more I realize that IE is a bit of a jerk when it comes to how it renders. In firefox and chrome everything works right but in IE my header is doubled in height. I'm not sure why. I've made everything divs and did all my positioning in css. here is my css.

website: http://www.discerningear.com

```
html { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; }
body {  background:#a99a6f; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
img { border-style: none; }
#slide{ max-width:100%; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #fff; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #fff; box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #fff; }
#container { -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000; box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000; text-align: left; width:800px; height:1500px; margin:0 auto; background:#d4d4d4; background-image:url("/includes/images/container.jpg"); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#header { width:100%; height:160px; padding:0 0 0 0; background-image:url('/includes/images/wave-header-background.jpg');}
#logo { float:left; height:80px; margin:5px; }
.logoImage{ content:url("/includes/images/DiscerningEar_Logo.png"); height:100%; }
#top_info { float:right; width:450px; height:40px; padding:0 0 0 0 ; margin:20px; }
#top_info  ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;}
#top_info  ul li { margin:0; padding:0px; float:left; }
#top_info  ul li a { display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 35px; background: url("http://dabuttonfactory.com/b.png?t=&f=Calibri-Bold&ts=18&tc=ffffff00&tshs=1&tshc=22222200&it=png&c=5&bgt=gradient&bgc=8c7f5e&ebgc=000000&bs=2&bc=a9996f&shs=2&shc=4d4d4d&sho=se&w=100&h=35") no-repeat; line-height: 35px; vertical-align: text-middle; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-shadow: #222222 1px 1px 0; }
#top_info ul li a > span { display: -moz-inline-block; }
#navbar {padding:20px 0 180px 0; height:60px; clear:both; }
#navbar ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;}
#navbar ul li { margin:0; padding:0px; float:left; }
#navbar ul li a { font-size:12px; float:left; padding:0 0 0 20px; display:block;}
#banner {  background-image:url('/includes/images/banner-background.jpg'); margin-top:-12px; width:100%; height:180px; clear:both; padding:0 0 0 0; text-align:center;}
#left_col { float:left; width:30%; height:600px; border:1px solid #333; color:#fff; padding:20px; }
#right_col { float:right; width:58%; height:600px; border:1px solid #333; color:#fff; padding:20px; }
#footer { padding:20px; clear:both; }
```

I dont know what would cause this but any help would be awesome. I'm continuing to look around for solutions but as of right now i guess i just don't know the best way to fix this.

Comment: Is the commented out code really necessary for the question?

Comment: Remove the comment before the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because of the [IE double margin bug](http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/).  It occurs in IE6 when a floated element has a margin applied as well (in your case, most likely the `#logo`).

The fix is to add:
`display: inline;` to that element's CSS.

Comment: Just as a note I'm currently running on a Mac so I can't test if my code will fix the issue or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responce. but unfortunately that isn't working. Is there a better way of writing any of the code for the header. maybe my newbism has allot to do with it.  :) thanks again for the quick responce.

Comment: @JamieNichols No, the code itself looks fine (especially since it works in other browsers), so it's most likely some other IE bug.

Comment: ok, i'll keep researching. oh and how does it look in safari? most likely much like it does in chrome

Comment: @JamieNichols Yep, looks the same as Chrome.